# File getting downloaded without extension, if there are special characters in file path in firefox

Tags: javascript, java, http, firefox, server

Files are kept in server folder with names `data/DIR Images/Img1.jpg`. when http request is sent from chrome browser, am able to download the file. But in Firefox file is getting downloaded without extension. `data/DIR` only its saving.

Comment: And how are you triggering the download? An HTML download link? Javscript? Something else?

Comment: java script 'window.open'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use URL encoding , if you are calling from javascript.

For example:

```
var uri = "download.asp?path=data/DIR Images/Img1.jpg";
var downloadURI = encodeURI(uri);
```

you will get the URL as

```
download.asp?path=data/DIR%20Images/Img1.jpg
```

The encoded url will work fine.

Comment: encodeURI am doing before window.open. But only problem is with Firefox browser. Chrome am able to download. in firefox file is getting downloaded without file extension along from %20 name is trimming off.

Comment: You can try using encodeURIComponent() - to encode params , Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/when-are-you-supposed-to-use-escape-instead-of-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent